# Is it possible to make this "complex" layout with Flexbox without adding div container around some parts of HTML code

Tags: html, css

I have a simple question.
Without adding divs on my HTML, is it possible to create [this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCREZ.jpg) only with Flexbox ?

I succeeded to acquire this layout by cutting my HTML structure with some divs (Two parts for the right and left side, etc..) but I'm stuck when I tried to do it without adding those divs.

[Here](https://codepen.io/Entry_Plug/pen/NmbbbY) is the HTML structure I would like to figure it out !

```css
        *{
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    main {
     height:100vh;
     display:flex;
     justify-content:center;
     align-items:center;
    }
    section{
     background-color:blue;
     height:800px;
     width:800px;
    }
```

```html
    <main>
 <section>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
  <div class="box5"></div>
  <div class="box6"></div>
  <div class="box7"></div>
  <div class="box8"></div>
  <div class="box9"></div>
 </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Only using flexbox without adding any div's it's not possible. It can be achieved using grids

Comment: @karthick. Thank you for your response. So I stop trying to do it that way ^^

Comment: Have a solution using extra div's which you might not like. But for reference  https://jsfiddle.net/sano6891/7z1r2054/

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to look at css grid instead, you can try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6yturLg1/

Essentially, you define a grid, then position the elements inside the grid wherever you want.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px;
}
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section div.box1 {
  background-color: #f00;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

section div.box2 {
  background-color: #f90;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

/* ... etc ... */
```

Comment: Thanks but, I try to do it with flex. And, it's not a square that is split in 4 div of 25%.

Comment: @WesK You can adjust the columns to be however you want in terms of size, I picked 4x25% because it was simpler and conveyed the idea making extra subdivisions. You could always create 8 or 12 rows instead of 4 if you want the extra subdivisions.

Comment: @WesK so the items in your layout have dynamic heights? then you should consider masonry layout - not possible with flexbox